# Assignment operator (=) in argument of Method Definition

Tags: c#, .net

See below method definition.

What is it called in C# where the equals sign is in method parameter.

Does it default method parameter initialization??

```
public List<Iabc> MyMethod(out List<Ixyz> faces, Type typeXYZ = null, int flag = -1)
{
    //...
    //...   
}
```

NOTE: Here `Iabc` and `Ixyz`  are any Interfaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're called optional (or named) arguments. MSDN usually has these things explained pretty well:

[Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

When using named arguments, be aware that changing argument names will break code. (where named parameters are used)

Also, remember that the default value is actually stored in the **call site** meaning that if you at some later point change the default value, code that is calling the method and was compiled before the change, will **still use the old value**. it might not matter in all situations but its something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

That's an [optional argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) in C# 4.0